# Deploying .PDB files in IIS. Any benefit?

Tags: .net, asp.net, web-services, iis

I am deploying ASP.NET and Web Service solutions to IIS for a **development** server. It looks like the last person that did this job deployed all the .pdb files too. I asked about it, and was told that they "provide better stack trace info in the logs" if they are left on the server.

Is there any truth to this? I've always left them behind, never deploying them to anywhere other than my local machine.

For an internal development IIS server (not production, not accessible to the outside world) is there any reason to or not to deploy the .pdb files? Is there anything bad that could happen? Do they really provide any benefit?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you are logging exceptions, then deploying the PDB files ensures that the exceptions include line numbers (so [Steven A. Lowe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9345/steven-a-lowe) has informed me on many occasions ;) )

Comment: So what does building an aplication in Release vs Debug do? anything? I'm used to the Java world where compiling debug inserts line#s and other debug info directly into the .class files.

Comment: Link here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/clr/thread/4de6861f-e723-4def-bcaf-aa717a3e1897/

Summary in Debug: No optimizations, [Debuggable] attribute added, PDB's deployed, #IF DEBUG conditionally compiled included, #IF RELEASE code not included.

Answer (score 40):

I always figured the .pdb files were only used by the debugger. If the runtime always checks for them for debug info, that should mean slower execution when throwing an exception, because it has to read the .pdb, right?

So I made a quick test:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace PdbSpeedTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
            try
            {
                Program p = new Program();
                p.Looper(0);
            }
            catch (NotImplementedException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
            }
            TimeSpan span = DateTime.Now - start;
            Console.WriteLine(span.TotalMilliseconds.ToString());
        }

        internal void Looper(int x)
        {
            try
            {
                if (x < 100)
                    Looper(x + 1);
                else
                    throw new NotImplementedException("blah!");
            }
            catch (NotImplementedException e)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException("blah!", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This just recurses 100 levels deep and throws an exception. Now for the runtime results:

Running as a **debug** build **with** the .pdb in the same folder:

```
C:\Work\PdbSpeedTest\bin\Debug>PdbSpeedTest.exe
   at PdbSpeedTest.Program.Looper(Int32 x) in C:\Work\PdbSpeedTest\Program.cs:line 37
   at PdbSpeedTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Work\PdbSpeedTest\Program.cs:line 16
31.2504
```

Running as a **debug** build **without** the .pdb:

```
C:\Work\PdbSpeedTest\bin\Debug>PdbSpeedTest.exe
   at PdbSpeedTest.Program.Looper(Int32 x)
   at PdbSpeedTest.Program.Main(String[] args)
15.6252
```

Running as a **release** build **with** the .pdb:

```
C:\Work\PdbSpeedTest\bin\Release>PdbSpeedTest.exe
   at PdbSpeedTest.Program.Looper(Int32 x) in C:\Work\PdbSpeedTest\Program.cs:line 37
   at PdbSpeedTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Work\PdbSpeedTest\Program.cs:line 16
31.2504
```

Running as a **release** build **without** the .pdb:

```
C:\Work\PdbSpeedTest\bin\Release>PdbSpeedTest.exe
   at PdbSpeedTest.Program.Looper(Int32 x)
   at PdbSpeedTest.Program.Main(String[] args)
15.6252
```

These were run from a regular old command prompt, not inside Visual Studio. So the .pdb definitely does add stack trace info, and slows down the exception handling.
Very interesting!

Comment: It probably should be **emphasized** that slower execution only occurs with exceptions--otherwise the impression is that .pdb files hurt performance, even with release builds. I don't believe performance is affected if your code is running smoothly without exceptions (which is why you shouldn't use write code that utilizes exceptions for normal branch control).

Comment: @KevinP.Rice and then you have the .NET framework that completely ignores it when it comes a very key and frequently used aspect, `Response.Redirect` which throws `ThreadAbortException` because .NET doesn't support true signals.

Comment: @ChrisMarisic Yes. This is a flaw. There is a work-around: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629

Comment: @ChrisMarisic: are you saying that the presence of the pdb file hurts performance when the `ThreadAbortException` is **thrown**, or only if you have a handler that actually asks for stack trace data?  I've handled the Redirect/ThreadAbortException problem by just ignoring that exception in my exception handler, and so I would expect that the pdb file doesn't hurt performance.  But is that wrong?

Comment: @JoshuaFrank i have not done any analysis but from the work detailed in this answer, i would assume in all cases when an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 8):

deploying .pdb files is helpful if you wish to remotely debug your application.

there is an MSDN article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t.aspx) explaining the process